# Do multi-dimensional arrays eat memory and how do I free up their memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, multidimensional-array

I have a complex tableview. Objective C

To populate a number of labels in each cell I had a multi-dimension table composed of 2 NSMutableArrays (1 embedded inside the other).  The result was an array that had 3 columns per row.

To free up memory I used
[arrayname removeAllObjects];

Well all I can say is that this did absolutely nothing.

This array (which per row was only holding about 130 chars of data and in this sample data I only had 30 rows) was like a virus that's favourite food was memory.  It ate chunks of 50mg like there was no tomorrow.

The removeAllObjects did nothing to recover memory.

I have searched high and low and find no clear way to free up memory when you are working with NSMutableArrays and it seems like multi-dimensional ones are cookie monsters.

In the end I removed the multi-dimensional array and just built a single NSMutableArray which was just all of the data concatenated into a string, which I then subStringed out the 3 pieces of data when I needed them.

Memory returned back to normal.

This may not have been the ideal solution.  Has anyone found a clear way of releasing the memory of NSMutableArrays ?

Comment: Please add a tag for the **language** you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if we knew what language you were using. If you're writing in C, just call

```
free(<array pointer>);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I removed the multi-dimensional array and just built a single NSMutableArray which was just all of the data concatenated into a string, which I then subStringed out the 3 pieces of data when I needed them.

Memory returned back to normal.

This may not have been the ideal solution but it worked

Answer (score 0):

Multi-dimensional `NSMutableArray` is unusual, but supported. It may not work the way you expect it to; it really is an array of arrays. In many languages, a "2D" array is really a wrapper around a multiplication function. This matters because with `NSMutableArray`, each subarray could be a different length, and you need to initialize and manage each of them.

But with ARC, the memory will be handled fine. You just have a mistake in your code. You're probably either retaining the subarray somewhere that you didn't mean to, or you aren't waiting for the autorelease pool to drain. But either way, arrays of arrays are fine in Cocoa.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I suspect you are right I must have not been clearing out a subarray somewhere but I couldn't see where.